# Are Android USB drivers interchangeable?

Tags: android, windows, sdk, 64-bit, drivers

i'm a beginner programmer, and i'm trying to start coding with android. I already set up my IDE(Eclipse), the SDK and all that, but I can't find a driver for my device. It's a Kocaso tablet, model M760. My question is, is the hardware on some tablets similar enough for the drivers to be interchangeable or no? Oh, and if someone knows where i can find a USB driver for that tablet, please give me a link? I promise I already searched on a lot of places ):

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this isn't the right site, I though it would be better than android power users :(

Comment: It's a definite maybe :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can root the tablet using these instructions;

http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/ice-cream-sandwich/44223-rooting-kocaso-m760.html

hopefully that will help you progress your work.

Comment: What do those instructions say? perhaps you could quote relevant parts?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the drivers are fairly generic, and therefore interchangeable. There is a USB driver in the SDK that will suit most needs, but there is a gotcha. You have to install it in the SDK, and then go in to the android SDK folder to install it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my tablet. After some research, I found the company that produces your tablet is [Global Phoenix Computer Technologies Solutions](http://www.globalpct.com). The website for their mid-size tablets (yours) is http://www.mymidpad.com. I found the User Manual for your tablet there under Downloads, but nothing else. Here is their contact information: [http://mymidpad.com/contactus.html](http://www.mymidpad.com/contactus.html). Send off an email or give them a call, and hopefully they can help you. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Edit: I doubt the Google USB drivers will work for you. They didn't for my Archos tablet. [This website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) lists the short list of supported devices, mainly big names. Your device is definitely not one of these big names, so you'll probably need drivers from GPCTS directly.

Comment: It's quite likely that the only reason the Google drivers would not work is that the VID doesn't match.  The actual protocol for talking to the device is usually the same.

Comment: Interesting. Can the solution be as simple as editing the android_winusb.inf file in android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver?

Comment: That would really depend on the interaction between windows and the driver - all we do on linux is add another VID to a config file for the adb tool, and add or edit a hotplug manager file to tell the operating system to let unprivileged users have access to anything with that VID which connects.  The point being that there is no software or driver unique to the new device.

Answer (score 0):

On my M752, I was able to force it to use the "Android Sooner Single ADB Interface" from Motorola, v 1.2.14.0 dated 11/25/2012. That seems to work OK so far for USB device ID = USB\VID_18D1&PID_0007&REV_0230&MI_01

That's a Google USB Vendor ID, so I was surprised to NOT find a match for the USB device ID in the latest Google USB drivers package [Android SDK Manager tool, extras, Google USB Driver revision 7.]

For lots of OEM drivers, see the page at:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers